# How to remove samples not fulfilling a certain predicate in Simulink / DSP Matlab?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, simulink

Let's assume the following setup:

I am using frame based processing in Simulink and I have fixed size frames of `[1000x1] double`.

Let's call this signal `s`.

**Question :** How can I produce a Simulink block, `b`, that removes all samples from `s` that do not satisfy a given predicate, say `-1<x<1`, where `x` is the sample value?

So, for example if I feed

`[0.5 -0.2 2 2 2 2 2 ...]` to `b`

then I would get `[0.5 -0.2]` because all the other samples do not satisfy the predicate `-1<x<1`.

**Summary:** I would like to create a `filter` operation in Simulink just like in functional languages like [Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions), Scala, ML, etc.

Is there a Simulink block like that already?

Or do I have to write my own ?

Comment: _Removing_ samples in a frame will result in a changing the output frame size for each frame. Is this really what you intend to do?

Comment: Yes, that is the main point because it will decrease the computational complexity in the blocks that consume the output of `s`.